# Existence of an electric/magnetic dipole of a molecule

Tags: representation-theory, molecules, dipole-moment

I have a molecule with a symmetry group $S_3=D_3$. I have to determine if it has a non-zero electric and/or magnetic dipole moment using the representation theory. I'm using the book of Jones "Groups, Representations and Physics". As far as I understood, the magnetic dipole moment exists iff the corresponding representation has an irreducible trivial subrepresentation. Is that right? What is the corresponding condition for electric dipole moment?

P.S. My knowledge in physics is very limited so I'm looking for a mathematical answer. Feel free to edit tags.